# Remove Layout background

Tags: android, cardview

Hey there i am using constraintlayout inside a cardview after applying cornerraduis i want to remove the extra background , i've tried to set the cardview and the constraintlayout background transparent but nothing changed. the layout is a bottomsheetfragment.
[Picture of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwezx.png)

layout of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.virtualmusem.views.LoginFragment">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:src="@drawable/museumicon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/email"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/singin_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:text="@string/please_sing_in"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_login_background"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_alternate_email_24"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/singin_text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_login_background"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/admin_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: i think you can just add a transparent background to the parent layout to get the expected result add @android:color/transparent as background of your layout...this should solve the issue

Comment: You need to add one parent layout and wrap your card view inside that parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

The corner radius is on the cardview not the BottomSheet, so try adding the cornerRadius to the sheet as well.

For MaterialComponents you can do it as below, otherwise a simple search will give you what you need.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    ....
    <item name="shapeAppearanceLargeComponent">@style/AppShapeAppearance.LargeComponent</item>
</style>
```

In the LargeComponent style set the cornerRadius

```
<style name="AppShapeAppearance.LargeComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Then add the overlay to your themes

```
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomSheetDialog</item>
```

There are other ways to do, it but bottom line, add the radius to bottom sheet as well or set background of bottom sheet to transparent.